# How can i find where the error is in a program that sometimes freezes

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

At least once or twice when i was running my program it was freezing, I couldn't click any button nor even close it because the Form was freezing.

At other times sometimes when i was quiting (form closing) the program just freezes.
I have tried to add try and catch to every method but it never stops there.

This is my top of Form1 and the constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool quitwithtimer;
        private int y;
        private int x;
        private IntPtr ID;
        private int counter;
        private int minutes;
        private int seconds;
        private DateTime dt;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool SetLocalTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct SYSTEMTIME
        {
            public ushort wYear;
            public ushort wMonth;
            public ushort wDayOfWeek;    // ignored for the SetLocalTime function
            public ushort wDay;
            public ushort wHour;
            public ushort wMinute;
            public ushort wSecond;
            public ushort wMilliseconds;
        }

        private int day;
        private int month;
        private int year;
        private int hour;
        private int minute;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label1.Text = "Test";
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size + 8f, label1.Font.Style);
            TimerCount.Text = "00:00";
            quitwithtimer = false;
            x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Width * 2;
            y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height * 2;
            counter = x;
            ID = this.Handle; //get handle of form
            minutes = 5;
            seconds = 0;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

Could be one of this DllImport make the problems sometimes ?

I have this method to get the current time and date but it never get to the catch when the program is freezing.

```
public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
        {
            DateTime networkDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
            IPAddress[] addresses = null;
            //default Windows time server
            const string ntpServer = "time.windows.com";
            const string ntpServer1 = "time.nist.gov";
            const string ntpServer2 = "time-nw.nist.gov";
            const string ntpServer3 = "time-a.nist.gov";
            const string ntpServer4 = "time-b.nist.gov";
            List<string> ntpServersList = new List<string>();
            ntpServersList.Add(ntpServer);
            ntpServersList.Add(ntpServer1);
            ntpServersList.Add(ntpServer2);
            ntpServersList.Add(ntpServer3);
            ntpServersList.Add(ntpServer4);

            // NTP message size - 16 bytes of the digest (RFC 2030)
            var ntpData = new byte[48];

            //Setting the Leap Indicator, Version Number and Mode values
            ntpData[0] = 0x1B; //LI = 0 (no warning), VN = 3 (IPv4 only), Mode = 3 (Client Mode)

            for (int i = 0; i < ntpServersList.Count; i++)
            {
                addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServersList[i]).AddressList;
                if (addresses.Length > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


            //The UDP port number assigned to NTP is 123
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresses[0], 123);
            //NTP uses UDP
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

            socket.Send(ntpData);
            socket.Receive(ntpData);
            socket.Close();

            //Offset to get to the "Transmit Timestamp" field (time at which the reply 
            //departed the server for the client, in 64-bit timestamp format."
            const byte serverReplyTime = 40;

            //Get the seconds part
            ulong intPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime);

            //Get the seconds fraction
            ulong fractPart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplyTime + 4);

            //Convert From big-endian to little-endian
            intPart = SwapEndianness(intPart);
            fractPart = SwapEndianness(fractPart);

            var milliseconds = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);

            //**UTC** time
            networkDateTime = (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds((long)milliseconds);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error" + err.ToString());
            }
            return networkDateTime.ToLocalTime();
        }

        // stackoverflow.com/a/3294698/162671
        static uint SwapEndianness(ulong x)
        {
            return (uint)(((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) +
                           ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8) +
                           ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) +
                           ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24));
        }
```

What could be make the program freezing sometimes once/two when running the program and in most of the cases when doing quit from the program.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close the form?", "Close Form",
                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    timer2.Enabled = false;
                    ChangeTimeOriginal();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

ChangeTimeOriginal()

```
private void ChangeTimeOriginal()
        {
            try
            {
                dt = GetNetworkTime();
                day = dt.Day;
                month = dt.Month;
                year = dt.Year;
                hour = dt.Hour;
                minute = dt.Minute;
                SYSTEMTIME time = new SYSTEMTIME();
                time.wDay = (ushort)day;
                time.wMonth = (ushort)month;
                time.wYear = (ushort)year;
                time.wHour = (ushort)hour;
                time.wMinute = (ushort)minute;

                if (!SetLocalTime(ref time))
                {
                    // The native function call failed, so throw an exception
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

How can i find the problem ?

EDIT**

This is all what i see and in the call stack window in the right bottom when the program freezing and when i did PAUSE.

It went to the line: socket.Receive(ntpData);
In the GetNetworkTime() method.

This is what i see now in the call stack window:

```
[External Code] 
>   TestDateTime.exe!TestDateTime.Form1.GetNetworkTime() Line 122 + 0xd bytes   C#
    TestDateTime.exe!TestDateTime.Form1.ChangeTimeOriginal() Line 272 + 0xe bytes   C#
    TestDateTime.exe!TestDateTime.Form1.Form1_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) Line 225 + 0x8 bytes  C#
    [External Code] 
    TestDateTime.exe!TestDateTime.Program.Main() Line 19 + 0x1d bytes   C#
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Have you tried pausing execution in the debugger (during a freeze) and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: @Cameron Are you kidding me? I've never thought of doing that myself in this kind of situation.  Excellent idea.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the reason that your application is freezing is because you're making calls to `GetNetworkTime()` which is in turn making IO blocking calls out to time servers. You should consider re-working this code to make these IO blocking calls on a worker thread. After you have fetched the results on the worker thread you can pass this data back to the UI thread via the `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()` constructs. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-async-and-await-for-beginners/) which should help.

Comment: Ok i used the pause suggested when it's freezing and it stopped on thel ine: socket.Receive(ntpData); in the GetNetworkTime() method. But it didn't show any exception or error message. How do i know what the problem is ? And maybe i need to add BeginInvoke() to each and each line in this GetNetworkTime() method ?

Comment: And how do i watch this line stack trace ? This line is painted with green. In the bottom right in the Call Stack window i see : > TestDateTime.exe!TestDateTime.Form1.GetNetworkTime() Line 122 + 0xd bytes             But i can't find any stack trace option.

Comment: I just updated my question . Still not sure what to do to solve it. If this is the only line that make the problem ? Uising BeginInvoke() on each and every line in the GetNetworkTime() method ?